# @Version number generation issue

Tags: annotations, version, eclipselink

I am migrating my application from Hibernate JPA to EclipseLink JPA. Here I am facing a problem of generating version number. Using @Version to generate version number for each row inserts and it will be stored in separate column(VER_NBR) in a table. When I insert a row in a parent table via Hibernate it generates 0 and for 3 child records it generates 1 for all records and in similar case if I insert via EclipseLink it generates 1 for Parent record and 2,3,4 for those 3 child records.

I am unaware of the concept behind Version number generation. @Version is using Javax.Persistence in both Hibernate and EclipseLink.

It made to fail the delete and updates in Eclipselink version.

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is. What do you mean by "it made fail the delete and updates"?

Comment: If your code isn't working in EclipseLink and the version isn't matching - are you sure it is inserting 3 separate child records?  EclipseLink too should use V1 for a v1, and of course you should be able to delete anything that isn't stale. So if it isn't, you have some issue in your code that, while it may work with another provider, doesn't fit the JPA model as is and may cause you other issues with other providers down the line.  One of the main difference out of the box is that EclipseLink uses caching. Check that your identity in the children is unique and set properly in your code.